# Intellij build doesn't set Maven property

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

We have a JavaFX Application with a `*.properties` file with the following entry:

```
# - ${project.version}
application.version=${project.version}
```

When we build the project with

```
mvn clean install
```

in the terminal or debug the application via IntelliJ the parameter gets set and our application shows the project version correctly:

```
# - 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
application.version=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Since updating IntelliJ to 2018.1 and the JDK to 1.8.0_172, one of our machines correctly sets the property on `mvn clean install`, but when debugging or running the application via IntelliJ the `${project.version}` won't be set in the target properties file.

Comment: care to share your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by reimporting the project with the project format .ipr. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the bug:

IntelliJ generates faulty *.iml files when importing a Maven Project with the project format ".idea (directory)" by not setting

```
org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true"
```

and the

```
<component name="NewModuleRootManager"
```

node at the start of the iml files. This results to faulty behaviour. Setting the project format to ".ipr (file based)" resolved my issue.